# Sharepoint development - multiple webparts in same solution, or project for each?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm working on a Sharepoint 2010 project that has quite a few visual webparts.

Currently I have all web parts in the same solution. My colleague is working on the same project, but is creating a project for each web part inside the solution.

What's the best practice here? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested both approaches when I started developing Sharepoint solutions and I conclude the following Pros / Cons:

Pros of having separate project for every webpart:

1. much faster deployment and testing of your code changes <- you don't have to deploy all the webparts everytime you make a single change.
2. easier and better team collaboration <- usually every developer works on a single webpart this way, everyone's code is separated and there won't be checkin/checkout conflicts.
3. better code reusability, if you needed at any time in the future to use a single webpart in another project you will find it much easier to just go and get the webpart project.
4. All webpart resources in a single place, usually the webpart uses some resources (resx / images) which you can include in it's project, imagine having a big solution and all the resources of all webparts are spread around in a single project, it's much harder to just get your webpart to use it in another future project because you have to find all related resources.

I hope that's enough to let you enjoy the Webpart per project appreach.

Comment: in this approach you can either deploy all webparts at once or a single webpart at a timl, which you don't have in the other approach. I hope this was helpfull

Comment: Good points. Any disadvantages? What about all the dlls that are created?

Comment: you can package them all in a single wsp inside visual studio, I didn't notice any disadvantages for this approach

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your response to my comment. What I meant, is are there any issues with having piles of dlls installed in the gac?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll mark this as correct as you have the most thorough answer. Looks like this is not a clear choice, however.

Comment: @Bassel - I ran into some problems deploying web parts in this fashion. I moved each of my web parts into their own project. This worked fine for the first 9, but when I got to #10 it wouldn't deploy. It couldn't get past the recycle iis step. I figured it was something with my code, so I created a plain web part and tried to deploy it as well. Same problem. Have you experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

All in one project unless there's a good reason to break them out (i.e. they need to be delivered separately).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Are there any other advantages / disadvantages that you could explain?

Answer (score 1):

It is about deployment. A single project results in a single wsp file, so if you want to deploy all web parts together, stick to the single project. Otherwise, split them up as appropriate.

Comment: It's likely that there will small changes to these (visual) web parts post-launch. Does that impact the choice at all?

Comment: Well, you'd still need to redeploy the whole wsp file for each change, but I don't think it should be a problem.

Comment: That's quietly incorrect, you can still deploy them all at once by just deploying the solution. even if every webpart is in a single project

Comment: Bassel is right. You can include all the web parts in a **solution** in a single WSP. So that's not a reason to go either way.

Answer (score 0):

If its a big project, a seperate project for each webpart could be an overkill. Unless there is a good reason (such as deployment), all should be in same project.

Comment: why would it be  an overkill? I have a solution with over 40 webparts, each in a project and it's flawless, much better than having to deploy the whole solution every time you want to test your changes.

Comment: In VS 2010, if you create SP project type for each webpart, it will generate 40 WSPs. Isn't it overkill ?

Comment: I don't see how is it an overkill when it gives you the flexibility of deploying a single webpart at a time.

Comment: not to mention that you can also deploy all the project at once by going to Solution Explorer -> Right click the solution -> Deploy

Comment: You might also want a seperate WSP for each content type then too ? And then seperate one for master pages, page layouts etc. It all depends on big your solution is.

Comment: and if you're worried about the number "40 wsps" you should worry more when you browse into the System32 directory which contains over 2700+ files and folders.

Comment: There is a difference between "solution store" and "file system" perhaps.

Comment: we're talking about webparts here, those are different

Comment: besides that you can package all webparts in a single wsp